# access an Ariel image dataset

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, dataset, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I want to experiment with a dataset to perform LULC semantic segmentation
I am trying to use the dataset in this paper [GitHub project page](https://github.com/RSandAI/LULCMapping-WV3images-CORINE-DLMethods) , the link to dataset is here: [dataset link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1a2FPc1-itu1V9_Q4n9aaWB4GV9MGeOqh) they gave me access to the dataset, and I can see the GT masks
however, I cannot see the images themselves they look like a solid black square. they are stored as tif files, but I could not open them on my Mac or in python, could you please help me with that so that I could start my project .. thank you

I tried different software and different python codes